# Render to QOpenGLFramebufferObject GL_HALF_FLOAT

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, render-to-texture

I want to render to a half float texture using QOpenGLFramebufferObject.
I try to create the fbo with the following code:

```
structureTensorTexture = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(
    renderWidth,
    renderHeight,
    QOpenGLFramebufferObject::NoAttachment,
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    GL_HALF_FLOAT
);
```

But when I run the program this message appears in the console:

```
[opengl\qopenglframebufferobject.cpp line 544] OpenGL Error: 1280
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing attachment.
```

If I use GL_RGBA instead of GL_HALF_FLOAT the error message doesn't appear, but this doesn't fit my purpose.

How can I render to a half float texture using QT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By providing an actual OpenGL image format. `GL_HALF_FLOAT` is not an *image format*; it's an enum that represents a type. You can use that as the [`type` in pixel transfer operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_type), but that's not an image format.

An [image format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats) that uses 16-bit floats would be `GL_RGBA16F`.